# DataReader Hanging when retrieving large recordset

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, oracle, datareader

My current situation is that I have an extremely large recordset (2 million records or so) I'm trying to query out of an oracle database using .Net and the `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` library (Ver. 2.112.2.0).

```
Imports Oracle.DataAccess.Client
Imports Oracle.DataAccess
```

... In my procedure:

```
Dim conn As New OracleConnection()

   ... connect to DB, etc (this all works fine) ...

Dim strSQLQuery = (Query for large recordset)
Dim cmd = New OracleCommand(strSQLQuery, conn)

   Using Reader As OracleDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    ...
   End Using
```

Now, this procedure works fine for smaller queries, but for this large query, it seems to hang indefinitely (I've waited up to overnight and then finally quit the program) on the `Using..` line and doesn't even get into the lines of code within the using statement... It seems to not be doing anything at all.

At first, I thought maybe this was an issue with my query itself, but when I try and run it using SQL Navigator, it returns the recordset within less than 10 minutes...

Am I doing something wrong? Is this normal? Is there a setting I can set to make the `OracleDataReader` not hang?

Also, even though this code is in VB, I'm equally comfortable with C#.

Comment: Does SQL Navigator actually return all values?  They could be wrapping your sql statement to only get like the top 100 results or something.

Comment: It returns the top 250, then you can click to keep getting more and more... If I choose to download it to a delimited text file, it takes a while, but it does it in less than 30 minutes or so...

Comment: Maybe the network buffer on your machine is filling up?  If so maybe you could simply break your query up into multiple smaller ones?

Comment: The network buffer is where the data stays until you start reading it in.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254931(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: thanks @smoore, I tried breaking it up to smaller queries, but it still hung... Maybe I need to break it up even more... Is there any way to force the size of the networkbuffer and, once it reaches that size, to start the datareader and then flush it and get more data or something like that that you're aware of??

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: @JohnBustos I met exactly the same trouble. Do you solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

This may sound stupid have you tried creating a reader without using a using statement. Here at work they recommend not doing a "Using" because we have seen bad things happen with bigger volumes of data when we do use a Using. So as a best practice we just create the reader in a new procedure so its scope ends at the end of the procedure.

Comment: VERY Interesting!! - I never tried that... I'm not experiencing this problem at this moment, but next time I do, I'll try that and if it works, I'll **HAPPILY** mark this as a solution... Thanks for the idea. Never thought of even trying that.